# returned an empty result set if columnName = float

Tags: php, mysql, sql, t-sql

```
select * from Table where data=2.6
```

After running the above query, db returned an empty result set. But Seen from table, there are many rows matching data=2.6 criterion.

Here the type of 'data' column is **FLOAT**. If changing the value to an integer like '**where data=2**', the matched result sets will be returned.

Please let me know if anyone see the error on the query? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`FLOAT` is "approximate numeric data type" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html), you should use `NUMERIC` instead.

Comment: Thanks @MatTheCat, but 'NUMERIC' type can not be selected from phpAdmin.

Comment: It's an alias for DECIMAL, maybe you can use this one? EDIT: or maybe not an alias but they have same properties ^^

Comment: Thanks again @MatTheCat, the 21.6 will be changed to 21.00 if using DECIMAL(10,2)